# Correlate registered voters with local election results

Tags: regression, correlation, modeling, log-linear

I have a list of voters that participated in my local election with their age, gender, and precinct. I also have a list of the results of this election by precinct. Is there any way to find relationships between the two sets of data?

Answer (score 1):

If the choice was between 2 candidates you could use logistic regression. But even with 3 or more there are categorical data models including generalized logits and loglinear models.  In SAS this can be accomplished using the catmod procedure.

Comment: At the moment I only have access to SPSS, but because of the way it works with cases there is a problem when I combine the two sets to data in order to run any models. The existing cases with voter info on each line end up having a random vote put on the same line and SPSS seems to interpret this as that vote belongs to the rest of the info on that case. Any idea how I would get around this?

Comment: Sounds like the files were not merged properly. It could be aproblem with your code or the way the data lines are being read in. It would not be a problem with the SPSS system.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in "predicting" which of 2 candidates won, then use logistic regression, as Michael suggested. If you are interested in understanding ("predicting") the proportion of people voting for one party, then use multiple regression.  Likewise, if you are trying to understand total voter turnout, use multiple regression.  Note, however, multiple regression can get complex, so if you are not comfortable with MR, you might simply calculate and plot the correlations between the demographic variables and the election data of interest.  That would tell you less than a MR analysis, but it would tell you something.